# Does a custom hook apply only to a specific component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook `useTheme()` that returns `{ theme, toggleTheme}`  where `theme` is a string and `toggleTheme` is a method to update theme variable

I have the following react:

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
 <Parent>
```

I am using the custom hook in both `Parent` and in `Child` components. When I call `toggleTheme` in `Parent`, the `Parent` is re-rendered (but the `Child` is not) and the `theme` is updated (using `useEffect dependency`).

But when I call `toggleTheme` in `Child` component, the `Parent` is not being re-rendered (but the `Child` is being rerendered) even though both are 'subscribed' to that hook.

Is a custom hook only to a specific component? Or if its not, then what am I doing wrong so that updates to the custom hook update both components?

I know redux is typically used for sharing state, but I wanted to see if there is a way to do it with custom hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have the 'same' Hook defined in Parent and Child, they are not sharing a state. You can confirm this using React Dev Tools - watch as the state of one changes, but not the other.

However, you don't need to bring in Redux just for this. A way to do it would be to define theme and toggleTheme in Parent, and then pass them as props to Child. Then they would change together.

Comment: Oh ok I did not know that, makes sense. Thanks